# Proof of commutative Artinian ring is Noetherian

Tags: proof-verification, commutative-algebra, ideals, noetherian, artinian

I think that I have a proof, but it seems much simpler than all proofs that I can find on the internet. Hence I suppose that there must be a mistake in my proof.

The commutative ring $R$ is Noetherian if and only if each ideal $I<R$ is finitely generated as an $R$-module (this is easy to prove).

Suppose that $I<R$ a nonzero ideal for $R$ a commutative Artinian ring. Now there must exist a pair $(j_1,J_1)$ such that $J_1<I$ strictly and $J_1+j_1R=I$. Inductively we construct a strictly descending chain which must terminate as $R$ is Artinian, say
$$I>J_1>J_2>...>J_n=0.$$
But then $I=(j_1,j_2,...,j_n)$, hence finitely generated. As $I$ was chosen arbitrarily all ideals are finitely generated and $R$ must be Noetherian.

Edit: I think the difficulty is in the existence of the pair $(j_1,J_1)$, is there any way to prove that such a pair does exist or that the idea is entirely wrong?

Comment: Well it exists because $R$ is noetherian, of course, but if you don't already know that I don't see any easy argument.

Comment: Yes of course, but do you think that there is an easy way of proving the existence without using that $R$ is Noetherian?

Comment: I think you're arguing as follows: take a minimal set of generators of $I$ and remove one element $r$; then denote by $J$ the ideal generated by the other elements and so $J\subsetneq I$ but $J+rR=I$. Alas, such a minimal set of generators may not exist.